# How to pivot second column in tsql

Tags: sql, t-sql

Here's my current dataset:

```
rname   ename
Advises Grad_student
Advises Faculty
Chairs  Department
Chairs  Faculty
```

I'm trying to get it into this format:

```
rname    ename1        ename2
advises  grad_student  faculty
chairs   department    faculty
```

Here's what i've tried so far:

```
select distinct 
r1.rname, r1.ENAME as ename1,r2.ENAME as ename2
from [dbo].[RELATIONSHIPS] r1
inner join(
select distinct 
RNAME, ENAME

from [dbo].[RELATIONSHIPS]) r2
on r1.RNAME = r2.RNAME
where r1.ENAME <> r2.ENAME

order by r1.rname
```

Here's what i'm getting back:

```
rname   ename1        ename2
Advises Grad_student  Faculty
Advises Faculty       Grad_student
Chairs  Department    Faculty
Chairs  Faculty       Department
```

How would I would I fix my code in order to get only 1 row back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` with `conditional aggregation`:

```
with cte as  (
  select rname, ename, row_number() over (partition by rname order by ename) rn
  from relationships
  )
select rname, 
  max(case when rn = 1 then ename end) ename1,
  max(case when rn = 2 then ename end) ename2
from cte
group by rname
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3333f/3)

Comment: Ok, that solves it, haven't seen cte before. Thanks!

Comment: @user2146212 -- np, ctes are `common-table-expressions` -- somewhat like temporary views.  The key to the solution is to use the `row_number()` to establish a grouping.

Answer (score 1):

In oracle

```
 select * from 
 (select rname,ename,
 RANK() over (partition by rname order by ename) Id
 FROM relationships)
 PIVOT(MAX(ename) for Id in (1 as ename1, 2 as ename2))
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are only ever two, then just do it this way. Short and sweet.

```
SELECT  rname,
        MIN(ename) ename1,
        MAX(ename) ename2
FROM relationships
GROUP BY rname
```